# Aggregate functions not working on S4 data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, class, aggregate, r-s4

I have a S4 object which inherits from a data.frame, but when I try to use `aggregate` on it, it does not work unless I explicitly pass the data.frame part of the object. Let me ilustrate it with an example:

```r
setOldClass("data.frame")

setClass("DataFrame",
         slots = c(
           data1 = "data.frame",
           data2 = "data.frame"
         ),
         contains = "data.frame")

df <- data.frame("a" = 1:6,
                 "b" = 2:7,
                 "c" = rep(c(1,2), each = 3))

df <- new("DataFrame", df)
```

Now if I execute `aggregate(a ~ c, FUN = mean, data = df)` it produces the following error:

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :
> 'data' argument is of the wrong type

Why is that? `df` inherits from data.frame, so that should not be a problem.
I know that executing `aggregate(a ~ c, FUN = mean, data = S3Part(df))` works as I want, but I would like to know why calling the data directly from `df` don't.

Answer (score 1):

S3 only chooses a method based on the first argument, which is `x` in the case of `aggregate`. So, the `data` argument is not used in choosing a method at all. Instead, because the first argument is a formula, `aggregate.formula` is called.

If you want to use the `data.frame` method, then you can use the `aggregate.data.frame` method directly, which has arguments `(x,by,FUN,...)` (see the help page on `aggregate` for more details).

It would be hard to write a S4 generic version of `aggregate`, because none of the arguments apart from `x` are shared between the different methods. Therefore the signature would have to be `x` only, which would basically replicate the S3 behaviour.

Another option is to write a method for `as.data.frame` for your new class (presumably returning the `@.Data` slot). This is called by `terms.formula` and so should solve your problem.